# Water for video games

Tags: shaders

Hey there Blender commune:)
I made a water shader in blender and it works in Evee can it also work in unity if it works in blender? 
here is a pic of my node setup:)
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Comment: What if I used PBR based work flow? like made a material fo it then baked all of the materials into image textures and then imported those into unity when done